# Where to ask questions regarding paranormal activities?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Just now me and some of my friends are having a conversation about the paranormal world, activities, ghosts, spirits and all. So I came home and searched on the Internet.

Then **stackexchange.com** came into my mind. I'm a big fan of  the Stack Exchange sites and want to know: is there any site where one can ask questions regarding paranormal activities and other related things?

Comment: Huuuuuuuuuuuuh!

Comment: hahaha, what was that @πάνταῥεῖ ??

Comment: Just a paranormal shudder ;-) I actually don't believe that such stuff can be   brought in shape in a definite FAQ like manner. _**"stackexchange forums"**_ Note that none of the SE sites is meant as a _forum_.

Comment: @Siraj "I'm not starting a conversation here," Yes, you are. Please take it elsewhere.

Comment: I'm skipping this in review for now only because the proposals in the proposed link are very dead.

Comment: The subject does not lend itself very well to a Stack Exchange site. Stack Exchange is very much about verifiable facts. The paranormal is usually hard to verify. But if it helps: there has been some academic research into parapsychology. Over here in NL, there was prof. dr. Tenhaeff. Googling that name _might_ give you a starting point for your research. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can propose a new site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com).

However there's currently a proposed site - [Paranormal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114464/paranormal) - that you should have a look at instead of creating a new proposal.